# Compiling Source Code Error

Tags: centos

While I'm compiling a open source project on Cent OS 5.5 I'm getting error "cc1plus warnings being treated as errors". Why and how to solve this problem.

Comment: You will need to provide a good deal more information than this in order to get a decent answer. What software are you compiling? What commands are you following? What warnings/errors are being produced?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is probably a -Werror flag being given somewhere. Assuming you have a project using automake/autoconf/make/configure, you can see if you find it somewhere in "configure" or "Makefile.am" or possibly in one of your environment variables.

Compiling programs with the -Werror flag is not a problem in itself, as the warnings are usually valid concerns about the quality of the sourcecode.

Try finding and removing the -Werror flag, possibly adding -fpermissive instead, and the code might perhaps compile. A lot more information is needed in order to be able to pinpoint why the source code you have (whatever it is) does not compile "by default".

Comment: You can try also './configure CFLAGS=-w'

Comment: Trying "./waf configure CFLAGS=-w" and "./waf CFLAGS=-w" is giving error like no such command found and even tried CXXFLAGS but the result is the same. And I know that the issue is because of -Werror but how to eradicate the -Werror thing guys.

Comment: More information is needed. Knowing that you're using waf is a start. Knowing which open source project this is, would help a lot. When it comes to waf, sometimes installing waf and running the installed version solves compilation issues, depending on how old the version of waf that comes with the project is. And, have you looked through the "wscript" file, if there is such a file?

Comment: This is the open source project url https://github.com/wayfinder/Wayfinder-Server

Comment: And Finally You suggestions solved issue Man. Thanks a ton guys.